# How to get the Git Commit message in Git Tower?

Tags: git, githooks, git-tower

I am using this script in the githook `commit-msg`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import re
ret = 1
try:
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as msg:
      res = re.match("^fix gh-[0-9]+.*$", msg.readline())
      if res != None: 
          ret = 0
except:
    pass
if (ret != 0):
    print("Wrong commit message. Example: 'fix gh-1234 foo bar'")
sys.exit(ret)
```

The problem is that Git Tower doesn't seem to include any arguments inside `argv`. How to solve this in a way that I can use git both from the command line as in a GUI like Git Tower?

Comment: This is a problem with SmartGit and other GUI tools too.

Comment: This sounds to me like a bug in Git Tower, as your hook looks fine. Since [they claim that hooks should work](https://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/faq-and-tips/faq/hook-scripts) (Albeit, messages should be printed to stderr), I'd contact [Git Tower Support](https://www.git-tower.com/support/contact) about this.

Comment: Check, contacted the support team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out with the help of the Tower support team.

In my example I wasn't able to grab the argument (ie: `#!/usr/bin/python`) by changing this to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` I was able to get it. Now `$1` contains the argument.

Complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# regex to validate in commit msg

    commit_regex='(gh-\d+|merge)'
    error_msg="Aborting commit. Your commit message is missing either a Github Issue ('GH-xxxx') or 'Merge'"

    if ! grep -iqE "$commit_regex" "$1"; then
        echo "$error_msg" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
```